# Update Rails Variable in ERB using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a dropdown menu of patients. When a user selects a patient from the dropdown menu, I want to use JQUERY to get that patient's ID, then make an AJAX call to the server to return that patient as a variable I can use in my view.

Dropdown:

```
    <%= f.select :patient_id, content_tag(:option,'select 
patient...',:value=>"")+content_tag(:option,'New 
Patient',:value=>"")+options_from_collection_for_select(@patients, 'id', 
'full_name'), :class=>"form-control" %>
```

JS:

```
 $('#assessment_patient_id').change(function(){
var e = document.getElementById("assessment_patient_id");
var patient_id = (e.options[e.selectedIndex].value)

if (patient_id == 0) {
  window.location.href = "/patients/new"
} else {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get-patient",
    data: {patient_id: patient_id},
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data)
    },
    error: function(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  });


}
```

Controller:

```
respond_to :js, :html, :json

      def get_patient
        @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
       respond_with @patient
     end
```

Routes:

```
  get 'assessments/get-patient', :to => 'assessment#get_patient'
```

get-patient.js.erb

```
$('#assessment-type').slideDown(350);
```

What I'm really trying to accomplish is the ability to go <%= @patient.method_name_here %> in my view *after* the user selects a patient from the drop down.

But I can't figure out how to get that data back as an object from the controller. Where does it go?

Comment: Is the success method firing?

Comment: It goes to `get_patient.js.erb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do something like this.  In the view add a div with the id#patient-name (for example)

Then, the js.erb file can update the dom.

```
# get-patient.js.erb

$('#assessment-type').slideDown(350);
$('#patient-name').html('#{j(@patient.name)}');
```

And, could this request go to patients_controller#show instead?

Comment: Wait - $('#assessment-type').html('#{j(@patient.name)}');  is literally just rendering #{j(@patient.name)} in my view

Comment: NVM: $('#assessment-type').html('<%=j @patient.name %>').html_safe